# Encrypt Result from tank auth always return different result

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

Did somebody know why the encrypt result from `tank auth` always return different results?

Comment: Tank auth library uses hash - not encrypt/decrypt method - and there is no way to "decrypt" hash. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Not familiar with it, but its probably creating its own salt from time or some other method. So if you encrypt the password "querty" 5 times you will always get 5 different hash returns.